# Android: onClick event not working and crashes the application

Tags: java, android

I am creating simple calendar app. Previously I used `Button` to change month images via the `.onClick` event. But, found typical to change its `backgroundTint` when user clicks on any button.

Then I use `AppComptButton` and I'm able to change its color by using `setSupportBackgroundTintList`. But new problem arises know the `.onClick` event is not working and crashes the application.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="344dp"
                        android:layout_height="360dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/Button_row1">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:text="Jan"
                    />
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private Calendar calendar;
    private int currentMonth;
    private SimpleDateFormat thisMonth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showDate();
        setColorofButton();
    }

    public void showDate(){
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        currentMonth = currentMonth + 1;
        String convert = Integer.toString(currentMonth);

        final int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("pg_000"+convert, "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(resID);

    }


    public void setColorofButton(){
        final AppCompatButton btn1 = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[0]}, new int[]{0xffffcc00});
        btn1.setSupportBackgroundTintList(csl);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
                updateCalander("pg_0001");
                break;

            case R.id.button2:
                updateCalander("pg_0002");
                break;

            case R.id.button3:
                updateCalander("pg_0003");
                break;

            case R.id.button4:
                updateCalander("pg_0004");
                break;

            case R.id.button5:
                updateCalander("pg_0005");
                break;

            case R.id.button6:
                updateCalander("pg_0006");
                break;

            case R.id.button7:
                updateCalander("pg_0007");
                break;

            case R.id.button8:
                updateCalander("pg_0008");
                break;

            case R.id.button9:
                updateCalander("pg_0009");
                break;

            case R.id.button10:
                updateCalander("pg_00010");
                break;

            case R.id.button11:
                updateCalander("pg_00011");
                break;

            case R.id.button12:
                updateCalander("pg_00012");
                break;
        }
    }

    public void updateCalander(String month){
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(month, "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(resID);

    }
```

Comment: Hi @varunbundel , could you post the crash log ?

Answer (score 0):

In your xml layout inside AppCompatButton (button1) you are referring imageView but where have you declared it in xml?.

Comment: Crash log would be helpful. But why are you referring imageview as @+id instead of @id in appCompatButton?

Comment: Hi I got the solution. But this logical or not i dont know. In layout file i use Buttons and in MainActivity.java file use store the Buttons Id in AppComptButton type variable and it works for Color change on Button and also onClick event works:

Comment: Glad that you got the answer. Cheers!